# System-wide shortcut to switch to a specific tab in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, hotkeys

I would like to set up system-wide shortcuts, that can be used from anywhere in Windows, to switch to the running instance of different websites. For instance, Ctrl+Shift-Y to mean "Look for a running instance of Firefox and switch to the tab containing "YouTube".

I know in Firefox I can use Ctrl+tabNumber (Ctrl+1 etc) to switch, but require something system-wide as I often have a YouTube video Or a Podcast playing in the background that I need to pause if someone comes to my desk or I receive a phone call. Since I'm using other Apps the above method is not suitable.

My Keyboard does have mute & volume buttons I prefer to pause so I can contine from where I left off.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a significant system you're requesting, non-trivial to develop. It would be far simpler to use one of the many possible methods of creating a mute keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I believe you may be able to write a command in CopyQ to do this.  See: https://github.com/hluk/copyq-commands  -- If you are successful, please post your results here.